# javascript resource file is not loaded in one project and loaded in other

Tags: javascript, asp.net, lost-focus

I have two identical ASP.net web application project. javascript resource file is not loaded in one project and successfully loaded in the other. I am not able to understand why and how to resolve. I am using the following to use javascript. the purpose is to solve the problem of lost focus described here [Reference link](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html)

```
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/FixFocus.js"  NotifyScriptLoaded="true" /></Scripts> </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

the following is the js file

```
                var lastFocusedControlId = "";

    function focusHandler(e) {
    document.activeElement = e.originalTarget;
}

    function appInit() {
    if (typeof(window.addEventListener) !== "undefined") {
        window.addEventListener("focus", focusHandler, true);
    }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(pageLoadingHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler);
}

function pageLoadingHandler(sender, args) {
    lastFocusedControlId = typeof(document.activeElement) === "undefined" 
        ? "" : document.activeElement.id;
}

function focusControl(targetControl) {
    if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
        var focusTarget = targetControl;
        if (focusTarget && (typeof(focusTarget.contentEditable) !== "undefined")) {
            oldContentEditableSetting = focusTarget.contentEditable;
            focusTarget.contentEditable = false;
        }
        else {
            focusTarget = null;
        }
        targetControl.focus();
        if (focusTarget) {
            focusTarget.contentEditable = oldContentEditableSetting;
        }
    }
    else {
        targetControl.focus();
    }
}

function pageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {
    if (typeof(lastFocusedControlId) !== "undefined" && lastFocusedControlId != "") {
        var newFocused = $get(lastFocusedControlId);
        if (newFocused) {
            focusControl(newFocused);
        }
    }
}

Sys.Application.add_init(appInit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the first project and start working in the second project which is identical. Now it is working perfectly